# I just want someone to check my work -- where do I post?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette

Where should we post questions that aren't necessarily looking for a detailed answer, but more geared towards just wanting a second set of eyes to look over your work and point out blatant mistakes or opportunities for improvement?

Answer (score 5):

The issue isn't asking for reviews of your work (this is DIY after all, and it would be silly to say you can't ask for help). A question should be specific for what it's looking for in an answer. A general "Here's what I've done. Does it look OK?" is likely to be closed as **Too Broad**.

Be specific in your question. Take pictures of the parts you're unsure about and be open about that uncertainty. The best examples here are those involving electrical work. Lots of people don't understand and want someone to check their work. A good example of this is [I replaced a surge arrestor for our home -- did I miss anything?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/120026/i-replaced-a-surge-arrestor-for-our-home-did-i-miss-anything)